# Wildfly 14 embedded Artemis: Define redelivery per MessageDrivenBean

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a JMS topic in Wildfly 14 embedded Artemis Broker. Now I want to define max-delivery-attempts and redelivery-delay. But I don't want to do it per Topic, but per Client, which is one or more MessageDrivenBean in an EAR-packaged application on the same server instance.

I am aware of the possibility to define address-setting in standalone.xml. But this is just possible per one ore more topic depending on wildcards.

Do I have any chance to define "max-delivery-attempts" and "redelivery-delay" per MDB which are listening to my topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client implementation underlying the MDB doesn't support it's own max-delivery-attempts or redelivery-delay logic. That functionality is implemented on the broker. Putting that functionality in the client wouldn't make a lot of sense as the broker supports a number of different standard protocols (e.g. AMQP, STOMP, MQTT) with implementations across many different languages and platforms. Putting the redelivery configuration on the broker is the only way to get consistent behavior across all those different clients.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well I see the issue with different protocols. However in my opinion it would be a nice feature to be possible to define it per client as there are already different parameters like subscription durability.